# How to configure title for mulitple UIButtons at once

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I want to change buttons title in below way, but get warning "Extra arguments at positions #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10 in call"

how could I make it work.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var firstrow: UIButton!
    
@IBOutlet weak var secondrow: UIButton!
    
@IBOutlet weak var thirdrow: UIButton!
    
@IBAction func SecondaryKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
        
        firstrow.setTitle("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        secondrow.setTitle("!","@","#","$","%","&","*","(",")", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        thirdrow.setTitle("`",";","'",",",".","?","(", for: UIControl.State.normal)
}
```

Comment: You have to add buttons for all keys. Single-button can not do this all action.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to change more than one button's behaviour with the `setTitle` method you have there, you are going to need an array of buttons.

If you already know what your button titles are going to be, and the length of your titles matches the number of buttons you have, you could do something like the following:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var firstrow: [UIButton]!

.... //Other lines of code

@IBAction func SecondaryKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {

    let titles = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

    for (index,button) in firstrow.enumerated() {
      button.setTitle(titles[index], for: .normal)
    }

}
```